# speeding up matrix corruption

Tags: python, random

I need to randomly erase 33% of the non-zero elements in each line of a matrix.

*Side note:* The end goal is to train a denoising autoencoder to remove this noise.

My solution:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(1000,3000)

for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    clean = matrix[i, :] # original matrix line
    # find non zero elements
    msk = np.nonzero(clean)
    assert sum(msk[0]) != 0
    
    # keep 66% of them
    idx = np.random.randint(0, len(msk[0]), size=max(1, len(msk[0])//3)) #erase at least 1
    msk = np.delete(msk, idx)

    dirty = clean
    dirty = [j if i in msk else 0 for i,j in enumerate(dirty)]
    assert sum(clean-dirty) != 0
    
    #save clean and dirty
    #...
```

My guess is that the bottleneck is drawing random numbers at each iteration.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to run quickly.

The idea is to use `nonzero()` grab the indices of non-zero elements. Use `choice()` to select 1/3 of them. and set those indices to zero.  Repeat for each row in the matrix.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

matrix = np.random.rand(1000,3000)

for k in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    r = matrix[k,:].nonzero()[0]
    n = round(len(r) * 0.33)
    i = rng.choice(r, n, replace=False)
    matrix[k,i] = 0
```

Comment: Why switch from their `len(r) // 3` to `round(len(r) * 0.33)`? More code and smaller values...

Comment: Also, you removed their "erase at least 1" aspect.

Comment: @superb rain, I missed the "erase at least one", because the comment was off the screen.  Using floor divide (`//`) means that *at most* 33% will be zeroed.  By using `round()`, I thought the average over all the lines would be closer to 33%.  Preferring `*` over `/` is just a very old habit.

Comment: `3000 // 3` is 1000. That's *more* than 33%. And more than your 990.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the text, the OP said "33%". Meh, I suspect they really meant a third, as suggested by their code.

Answer (score 3):

> My guess is that the bottleneck is drawing random numbers at each iteration.

Why guess when you can measure? I changed the height to 100 so the whole thing takes me about 8 seconds, reasonable to play around with. Removing the `assert` line on the bottom makes it a bit faster. Also removing the `dirty = [j if...]` line makes it **a lot** faster. As you'd expect from that inefficient line.

Not sure why you're making it so complicated. I think `clean[idx] = 0` does the deletions you want, and it's fast.

Comment: I'm not sure. If I do `dirty[idx] = 0` then `dirty` is unchanged and still equal to `clean` (assertion error). But I agree, that line sucks.

Comment: What makes you think `dirty` is unchanged? It's not. About them being equal after the change: Yeah, of course they are. With `dirty = clean` you make them the **same object**. So if you change that object through one of those variables, of course you then also see the change through the other variable. If you want `dirty` to be a copy (which you can change independently), then make it a copy. Although I'd maybe instead simply store the clean version *before* making the change.